# php oop chaning fetch from mysql

Tags: php, oop, chaining

I am new to chaining, and I am trying to prototype a small chaining class but I have run into an issue. When I chain 2 simple queries, they borrow from one another and I do not really get why.

```
private $test_sql;
private $test_limit;

public function test_get_data($test_table)
{
    $this->test_sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$test_table;
    return $this;
}

public function test_limit($test_limit = '')
{
    if ($test_limit != '') {
        $this->test_limit = ' LIMIT '.$test_limit;
    }
    
    return $this;
}

public function test_all()
{
    $sql = $this->test_sql . $this->test_limit;
    
    $row = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $row->execute();
    $query = $row->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
    return $query;
}
```

....

```
$test1 = $data->test_get_data($table)->test_limit(2)->test_all();
$test2 = $data->test_get_data($table2)->test_all();
```

The test_limit also applies to test2 when it's not present in the second chain. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, seems all it needed was an else argument to escape the previous value:

```
public function test_limit($test_limit = '')
{
    if ($test_limit != '') {
        $this->test_limit = ' LIMIT '.$test_limit;
    } else {
        $this->test_limit = '';
    }
    
    return $this;
}
```

although I also have to specify the second chain empty as well:

```
$test1 = $data->test_get_data($table)->test_limit(2)->test_all();
$test2 = $data->test_get_data($table2)->test_limit()->test_all();
```

Is there a way to make the chain skip the test_limit() and take the empty default value from the function?